# substitution lemmas for first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, satisfiability, hilbert-calculus

How can i prove $ \text{$\models$}_{\Sigma}  ((\forall x \ \varphi ) \ \Leftrightarrow   \ (\forall y \ [\varphi]_{y}^{x}))$.

Being $ \Sigma $ a signature, $ \varphi$ a formula, and $ [\varphi]_{y}^{x} $ the subsistution of $ x$ by $ y $.

When $ y$ is not in the free variables of $ \varphi$ and $y \triangleright_{\Sigma} x : \varphi$, which means that $x$ is free for $y$ in  $ \varphi $

In my opinion i would have to use the substitution's lemma or the one of the hidden variables  but i just can't seem to find a way to prove it.

Comment: Couldn't you prove the theorem were true for each of the conditional conjuncts of the bi-conditional using the rules for substitution and induction on the relevant formulae, and then just concatenate the two conditionals?